# clip-path: Black background instead of transparent

Tags: css

I'm using `clip-path` to generate a little curve on one of my div elements

```
.nav
{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 6%, 50% 0%, 100% 5%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 6%, 50% 0%, 100% 5%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

[image: Black background on border]

As you can see, there is a black background on the border, but I've set it to transparent. If I change the color to red, the black background will be red. My question is now: How can I use a transparent background?

Comment: What's the background of the page? Can you create a demo?

Comment: Voted to close as *not enough code to reproduce the problem* because the code given in question will not cause a black border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `clip-path` which has less browser support try using `pseud-elements`

```css
body {
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/500/500/any');
  background-size: cover;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:200px;
  font-size:26px;
}
.nav:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -50%;
  top: 0;
  background: #00CCFF;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
.nav:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left: 50%;
  background: #00CCFF;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">Moin</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you want to use the clip path method, you can try this one,

http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/VvqROX

```css
h1,

.description {

  text-align: center;

  margin: 5px 0;

}

/** The Clip Box **/

.content {

  position: absolute;

  margin: auto auto;

  top: 0;

  right: 0;

  bottom: 40px;

  left: 0;

  width: 500px;

  height: 100px;

  padding: 20px;

  background: #3498db;

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 30px, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 30px), 50% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 30px));

  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 30px, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 30px), 50% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 30px));

  -webkit-transition: all 200ms;

  transition: all 200ms;

}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h2>Clip-Path Example</h2>
</div>
```